# Excel Macro - disabling "file now available for editing" msg

Tags: vba, excel

How do you disable the pop up message:

> File now available for editing.

in Excel?

I couldnt do it in my python code so I am trying to see if I can do it within Excel macro.  Do I apply the macro to the master copy, or the one I am opening up as read only?

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts=False`?

Comment: There looks to be several solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605823/prevent-file-now-available-popup-excel?rq=1) post.

Comment: @Foxfire yes but that didn't work